# How can I offer multiple module formats for subfiles of a published npm library

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, package.json, rollup

Given a package published on npm with a `package.json` that points to 3 separate distribution files, and that looks something like this:

```js
{
  ...
  "name": "@myorg/mymodule",
  "main": "mymodule.umd.js",
  "module": "mymodule.esm.js",
  "unpkg": "mymodule.min.js"
}
```

and the public usage looks like:

```js
import mymodule from '@myorg/mymodule'

mymodule() // ..does stuff
```

or when using commonJS

```js
const mymodule = require('mymodule')

mymodule.default()
```

How do I structure my package to publish additional imports. For example, let’s say we want to publish a feature, or localization, and we don’t want that to be part of everyone's bundle, because only a few people will need that feature. Ideally the usage would look like:

```js
import mymodule from '@myorg/mymodule'
import fr from '@myorg/mymodule/fr'

mymodule({
  locale: fr
})
```

How can I structure my package to allow for this? Technically I'm able to do these imports, but if I publish an `esm` webpack or rollup fails (Unexpected token 'export') because they think it should be commonjs build and if I publish a `umd` they throw warnings about not being able to find the default `export`. The only effective way I was able to get this to work is when explicitly importing `import fr from '@myorg/mymodule/fr.esm'`

However, as a package maintainer, I would like to pre-configure the package to work better with the bundlers instead of requiring users to understand the internals of their bundler, or rely on their tree-shaking to reduce size. This already works great with `main`, `module`, and `unpkg` for the main file, how can I do something similar for other files?